# Failing to prove that E(XY) is an inner product

Tags: probability-theory, lp-spaces, inner-products

Let $L^p$ be the space of all functions with finite p-moment and let $X,Y \in L^p$.
Since $L^p$ is a vector space, I thought I could make it an inner product space with $E(XY) : L^p \to \mathbb R$ as the inner product. 
I have, for $X,Y,Z \in L^2, \lambda\in\mathbb R$:

1. $E[(X + Y)Z] = E[XZ + YZ] =E[XZ] + E[YZ] $
2. $E[\lambda X] = \lambda E[x]$ both by the linearity of E
3. $E[XY] = E[YX]$ is obvious

The definiteness is causing me problems tough.
I thought that, since
$E[XX] = E[X^2] = \sum_{x\in\mathbb R}x^2p(x)$ (the continuous case is basically the same), with $p(x)$ positive by definition and $x^2$ always positive, we had that $E[X^2]$ is positive for every $X$ and is $0$ if and only if $X$ is almost surely equal to $0$. But then I tried to use this inner product with $X = X-E[X]$ and $Y = Y - E[Y]$ to define the covariance, but I found that $E[(X- E[X])^2] = 0$ for every X almost surely constant, not only almost surely $0$. How can it be, since $x^2$ is always positive? I saw on wikipedia that there is a workaround with a quotient space, but I would like to understand why my approach failed.

**EDIT:**
Basically the questions are:

1. Let $X\in L^2$ be a random variable. Then
   $E[X^2] = \sum_{x\in \mathbb R}x^2p_x(x)$. How can such a sum be $0$ if $X$ is not almost surely equal to $0$?
2. Is it possible to define a quotient space of $L^2$ such that $E[XY]$ is also positive definite and thus an inner product? If yes, how?

Comment: The reason why you are having trouble doing this is it can't be done.  Read about $L^p$ spaces somewhere (real analysis book, wikipedia).  The dual space for $L^p$ is $L^q$, where $1/p + 1/q = 1$.  When $p =2$, then $q = 2$ as well, so 2 is special.

Comment: You are supposing that $X,Y\in L^p\implies XY\in L^p$.

Comment: I am supposing that if $X,Y\in L^2$, then $XY\L^1$, which I can prove (there's also a proof from my textbook)

Comment: I'm sorry, probably my first comment was inappropriate.  After your introduction with $L^p$,  it turns out you are only interested in $L^2$, is that right?  And you want to know why $L^2$ is an inner product space?

Comment: Yes I am, since $\forall p>=2, L^p \subset L^2$ and if$X,Y \in L^1$ only, I am not guaranteed that the covariance exists. (Thank you for the response anyway)

Comment: If I take what you wrote literally, you assume  $X = X - E(X)$, so $E(X) = 0$, and you also assume $X$ is constant almost surely, say $X = c$ a,s.  Hence $0 = E(X) = E(c 1) = c P(\Omega) = c$.  So you have assumed $X$ is the zero random variable.  Then it is not surprising that $E(0 - E(0)^2)) = 0$.  But maybe you have a typo, so this is not what you meant at all?

Comment: That is not what I meant. I edited the question: now it should be more clear. Please, give it a look

Comment: If you claim not to mean what you literally wrote, then you had better write what you you meant instead.  As for what you wrote after the EDIT, if $E(X^2) = 0$, then $X = 0$ a.s., as you can prove.  $L^2$ is already an inner product space, and there is no need to take a quotient.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72890/discussion-between-fredgoodman-and-user258607).

Comment: Your inner product **isn't** definite positive. If $X\ne 0$ but $X = 0$ almost everywhere, then $E[X^2] = 0$.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not know how to say this rigorously: Can I define a quotient space such that $X, Y$ are "equal" if they are equal on a subset of the sample space of probability 1? i.e. they are equal if they are almost surely equal

Comment: Yes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_spaces.

Comment: One ALWAYS does that.  The elements of $L^2$ are, by convention, not really functions but rather equivalence classes of functions, with precisely your equivalence relation.  Perhaps this is the point you are stuck on.

Comment: One always does that because nothing in the probability setting could possible distinguish between two functions that are equal a.s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After quite a bit of discussion, I finally worked out what the issue is, I think.  Maybe it's worth recording this as an answer.

Let $(\Omega, P)$ be a probability space.   Say two measurable functions  (random variables) $X$, $Y$ on  $\Omega$ are equal almost surely (a.s) if the set of $\omega \in \Omega$ such $X(\omega) \ne Y(\omega)$ has probability zero.  This is an equivalence relation. Moreover, the set $\mathcal N$ of functions $X$ such that $X = 0$ a.s.  is a linear space.

There are two possible definitions of $L^2 = L^2(\Omega, P)$:

Let $V^2$ be the linear space of measurable functions  $X$ on $\Omega$ such that $E[X^2] < \infty$.  This is *almost* an inner product space, but positive definiteness fails in case $\Omega$ has non-empty subsets $A$ with $P(A) = 0$.  Consequently, if one tried to work with $V^2$, one would have a lot of annoyances:  convergent sequences with non-unique limits for example.

Let $W^2$ be the set of equivalence classes of functions $X$ in $V^2$ for the equivalence relation of equality a.s.  Equivalently, $W^2 = V^2/\mathcal N $.  Then $W^2$ is still a linear space and the *almost* inner product on $V^2$ induces a genuine inner product on $W^2$.

The usual convention in mathematical analysis and in measure theoretic probability theory is to take $W^2$ rather than $V^2$ as $L^2(\Omega, P)$.  Nothing is lost by doing this.  The only difficulty is that one has to remember that elements of $L^2$ are not actually functions but equivalence classes of functions.

The OP discovered both the difficulty in working with $V^2$ and the solution to the difficulty, which is to replace $V^2$ with $W^2$.

Comment: Thank you. This answer describes well the process that I went through and confirms that I am on the right path now